# simple form tutorial, php method doesnt invoke

Tags: php, jquery, xampp

i'm doing some simple tutorial from jQuery and as for now i have problems with php script, sending data from the input form...
My input form looks like follows:

```
<form method="post" action="submit_to_db.php">
<div id="container">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

    <label for="email">E-mail address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

    <label for="comments">Any comments</label>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="35" name="comments" id="comments"> </textarea>
    <br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send costam" />
</div>
</form>
```

The script for jQuery is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#submit').click(function() {
                $('#container').append('<img src="a.gif" alt="Please w8" id="loading"/>');

                var name = $('#name').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                var comments = $('#comments').val();

                console.log(name, email, comments);

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'submit_to_db.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email +     '&comments=' + comments,
                    success: function(result){
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Ok, so why after I clicked the Submit button the action isnt invoked... i mean my database isn't changing, no data is added and my browser just present the code for submit_to_db.php... Maybe it can be useful that I'm using XAMPP and at the beginning I had to change my localhost's port to 81 - in httpd. conf I chinge Listen: 80 to 81...

Really sorry for such n00b question, I really don't know how to move on with this tutorial :( thanks a lot for ur help.

Ahh. Just in case - php file:

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost:81', 'root', '', 'my_db');
    $query = "INSERT into comments(name, email, comments) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
    if($stmt->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'],     $_POST['comments']);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to first prevent the default action for the button....

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: $('#submit').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();  //rest of instructions }    that will stop the form from submitting like normal, and run the javascript....what does you console.log(result) return?

Comment: So what errors are you getting? You really need to narrow down the issue.  Is it in the server-side script? Is it in the client-side javascript?

Answer (score 0):

As comments pointed, the submit button does his default action while you are waiting for the ajax.
You can get the form to use your function instead of the form action by selecting the form and using the submit method, like this :

```
$('form').submit(function(){
/// function goes here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments about preventing the default action, you may also need to url encode your query string.  Otherwise things that are written in the forms could potentially cause problems in your query string.